# how to call modules' model and controllers files in a controller in laravel 4.1

Tags: php, laravel, module, laravel-4

I created a modular system by using laravel 4.1 I have a tree scheme as follows:

```
app/
app/controllers/
app/modules/
app/modules/modulename/
app/modules/modulename/controllers/
app/modules/modulename/controllers/modulecontroller.php
app/modules/modulename/models/
app/modules/modulename/models/modulemodel.php
```

What I want to do is to call the model from a controller in app/controllers/ class.
How I can call that module and its model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `/app/modules` is added to your `composer.json` file's `autoload` : `classmap` and issue `composer dump-autoload` or `php artisan dump-autoload`. Then you can just create an instance like `new ModuleModel` or whatever name you gave your class. Though it's better to pass to your controller by dependency injection. This way your code will be easier to test because you can pass in stub data.

```
public function __construct(ModuleModel $module_model_instance) {
   $this->module_model_instance = $module_model_instance;
}
```

Comment: Ok it works now but I have another problem. I use eloquent in my model and hence it gives me the error: Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException Class 'App\Modules\Modulename\Models\Eloquent' not found How can I solve this?

Comment: Seems like you have your code namespaced. If so add use Eloquent; after the namespace declaration.

Comment: It worked, either. Thanks but I noticed now that, if I use namespace in my controller in app/controllers/, my functions starting with App() break down. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: You should add `use ...;` for all the classes outside your own namespace. You can do for example `use Eloquent, Input, Validation;`.

Comment: Do you mean `App::`? If so add this to your `use ...;` too!

Comment: Yes it is. I am trying to use App::()... But what am I supoosed to use?

Comment: Maybe start a new question because the answer could help other people and this comment line will become to long. :)

Comment: Ok :) It continues in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512489/how-to-use-different-namespaces-in-a-controller-in-laravel-4-1

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather add this as a comment but have insufficient rep.

If everything is correctly autoloaded by composer in the PSR-0 (or 4) section, then you should just be able to reference it using it's namespace?

I sometimes need to run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

to refresh the autoloaded files, especially if using vagrant.

Hope this is helpful. I'm not sure if I've fully understood your problem.

Comment: ok it worked thanks. But I have another problem. I use eloquent in my model and hence it gives me the error: 

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'App\Modules\Modulename\Models\Eloquent' not found 
How can I solve this?

Comment: use \Eloquent instead of Eloquent, in your model.

Comment: As @SUB0DH said, namespace paths are relative. You can either use \Eloquent or \Exception etc to reference "root" classes, or use "use" statements at the top of your class to remap them. 

e.g. 

    use \mymodule\myUser as User;

Putting

   use \Eloquent;

as the top will map it correctly so that you don't have to change other mentions within your class.