# how to use different namespaces in a controller in laravel 4.1

Tags: php, laravel, module, laravel-4

What I want to do is to use different namespaces in a controller. I have a tree scheme like this:

```
app/
app/controllers/
app/modules/
app/modules/modulename/
app/modules/modulename/controllers/
app/modules/modulename/controllers/modulecontroller.php
app/modules/modulename/models/
app/modules/modulename/models/modulemodel.php
```

What I want to do is to call a model from a controller in app/controllers/ folder. Therefore I am supposed to add namespace as follows:

```
    use App\Modules\Facebook\Controllers\Facebook;
```

The problem is that when I add a namespace and use App::() function at the sametime, I get the following error:

```
    Class 'App\Modules\Modulename\Controllers\App' not found
```

I think it is looking the `App::()` function in module folder. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you add a few of your controller namespaces. I think you are doing something wrong there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use `App` inside your `App\Modules\Facebook\Controllers` namespace, it will be interpreted as `App\Modules\Facebook\Controllers\Facebook\App` class.

since you don't want to have the previous namespace, you use a `\` before `App` like:

`\App::()`

or put a use statement of top the class like `use App;`

Answer (score 1):

if you say

```
use App\Modules\Facebook\Controllers\Facebook;
```

then you are supposed to use `Facebook` instead of `App`... Or don´t I understand your problem correctly?

if you say

```
use App\Modules\Facebook\Controllers\Facebook as FacebookController;
```

the you can use `FacebookController` in your file

if you need Access to the **root** App, you need to to root it using a leading `\`

```
\App::make()
```

Comment: Ok I can use it. But the main problem is that I want to use laravel's App::() function at the same time in the same controller. That time App::make() function gives me error like this:  Class 'App\Modules\Facebook\Controllers\App' not found

Answer (score 1):

You probably are creating an unusual namspace scheme. It appears you are namespacing every class from your module differently. You should namespace your code within your module only, like so:

```
// Adding Onur to the namespace prevents any future namespace collisions.
<?php namespace Onur\Facebook;
```

After creating your namespace you should add all classes that are outside of your namespace that you want to use as followed.

```
use Eloquent, Input, Validate, Etc;
```

This prevents you from adding a `\` in front of every class instance, making your code hard maintain and prone to errors. It also gives you a good overview on all the classes you are using in the current class.